# Publishing doesn't update the API (Azure Mobile Service)

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

After I publish my mobile service through Visual Studio, the online API doesn't change. It's driving me insane.

The publishing process returns no errors, it says that the site was published successfully although I don't see any changes in the API.

This is the API running on localhost, with the changes made: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHKtD.png

Everything compiles correctly and works in localhost. All I wanna do is publish it so I can use it on my mobile service.

This is the API after I publish it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/91dHC.png (as you can see it's not the one that I just published, it's unchanged)

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Solved it guys! I went to the Mobile Service tab at manage.windowsazure.com and pressed "RESTART". Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same for me - deleting the browser cache didn't help. BUT I restarted the mobile service in the Azure Portal and then the new endpoints showed up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, finally got what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is probably just caching the page. If you can connect to the new table endpoints, then they are definitely there. Try using a different browser or running in Incognito or InPrivate mode.